# I am trying to add more variables automatically, which i don't know

Tags: python

**I want to automate and add more of (atr1,2,3,4,etc) and (karatr1,2,3,4,etc)**
**I would be happy if you helped. <3**

```
giriş = float(input("Giriş yapma anı: "))
atr = float(input("Girişteki atr değeri: "))

atr1= (atr)
atr2= (atr*2)
atr3= (atr*3)
atr4= (atr*4)
atr5= (atr*5)
atr6= (atr*6)
atr7= (atr*7)
atr8= (atr*8)
atr9= (atr*9)
atr10= (atr*10)

karatr1 = float((giriş+ (atr1) ))
karatr2 = float((giriş+ (atr2) ))
karatr3 = float((giriş+ (atr3) ))
karatr4 = float((giriş+ (atr4) ))
karatr5 = float((giriş+ (atr5) ))
karatr6 = float((giriş+ (atr6) ))
karatr7 = float((giriş+ (atr7) ))
karatr8 = float((giriş+ (atr8) ))
karatr9 = float((giriş+ (atr9) ))
karatr10 = float((giriş+ (atr10)))
```

I looked at some forums but they didnt really help

Comment: why not use a dictionary? `atr = {1: some_number, 2: some_other_number, ...}`?

Answer (score -1):

First dont use Turkish characters in variable names.

Try this :

```
giriş = float(input("Giriş yapma anı: "))
atr = float(input("Girişteki atr değeri: "))

atrcnt=10

atrlist=[item * atr for item in list(range(0,atrcnt))]
karatrlist=[item + giriş for item in atrlist]
#and then if you want
karatr1,karatr2,karatr3,karatr4,karatr5,karatr6,karatr7,karatr8,karatr9,karatr10=karatrlist
```

but if you want to automatic creation of variables like ***karatr1*** etc. you need to find a way to create your python file automatically.

Otherwise lists, dicts and smilar structures are built for this.